# Any way to advance along Google Directions route by X minutes?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have my route from the Google Directions API, it has its start and end and a bunch of points in between. Is there any way to figure out where you would be if you start at one point and follow that route for X minutes?

Basically, is there any way to get a segment of a route with a length of a specific amount of *travel time* and not just distance?

Comment: @geocodezip has a complete example of that [on his website](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-timeOnRoute.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say (as I presume from your question) that you've got a valid [google.maps.DirectionsResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsResult) object.

This object has a `routes` property, which is an object of type [google.maps.DirectionsRoute](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsRoute). Usually you will have just one route. Said route will have a `legs` property which is an array of [google.maps.DirectionsLeg](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsLeg).

At this point, you could say that you have a variable `legs` which is

```
var legs = myDirectionsResult.routes[0].legs;
```

There can be one or more legs (according to your waypoints). Each leg will have a `steps` property, which is an array of [google.maps.DirectionsStep](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsStep).

Each step has properties such as `start_location`, `end_location`, `duration` and `distance`.

So, finally, you can get the steps of your route as:

```
var steps = myDirectionsResult
             .routes[0]
             .legs
             .reduce(function(accum,leg) {
                accum=accum.concat(leg.steps); 
                return accum;    
             },[]);
```

Now you can iterate over the steps until you reach your time limit:

```
var currentStep,
    duration,
    start_location,
    end_location,
    timeSpent,
    totalSteps = steps.length,
    timelimit = 900; // seconds.

for(var i=0; i < totalSteps; i++) {
   currentStep = steps[i];
   duration = currentStep.duration.value;
   start_location= currentStep.start_location;
   end_location = currentStep.end_location;
   if(timeSpent + duration > timelimit) {
     break;
   }
   timeSpent = timeSpent + duration;
}
```

So let's break this down. You have an array of steps and a time limit. You iterate over the steps. At the beginning of each step you check if completing this step will take your travel time beyond your time limit, in which case you break the loop. Otherwise, you add the duration of the step to your spent time and proceed to the next one.

Since you started declaring that your timelimit was 900 seconds, you will eventually reach a point in which you've spent 850 seconds, and the current step has a duration of 100 seconds, so you cannot complete this one. You've set the starting and ending locations of this step, so you break the loop and you know you can reach somewhere between those two locations until you complete your time limit.

In this case, the step has a duration of 100 seconds and you only have 50 seconds left, so you know you have reached the midpoint between the start and end location of the current step. You need to interpolate between those locations to know the final coordinates. You can do this manually in case you consider that, for small distances, the difference between coordinates behaves like they would on a cartesian plane. (See [Small Angle Aproximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation)) but you could also use the geometry library of google maps (see [google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#spherical.interpolate))